# translate Greek quote at the start of Boethius Consolation of Philosophy? Something about kalon

Tags: aristotle

I was wondering if someone could translate the following quote into English for me.

ὄμως δὲ και ἐν τούτοις διαλάμπει τὸ καλὸν,
ἐπειδὰν φέρῃ τις εὐκόλως πολλὰς καὶ μεγάλας
ἀτυχίας, μη δι᾿ ἀναλγησίαν, ἀλλὰ γεννάδας
ὤν καὶ μεγαλόψυχος

I encountered it at the start of the Consolation of Philosophy by Boethius. It then provides the following in brackets:
Greek: homôs de kai en toutois dialampei to kalon,
epeidan pherê tis eukolôs pollas kai megalas
atychias, mê di analgêsian, alla gennadas
ôn kai megalopsychos.

Aristotle's 'Ethics,' I., xi. 12

I ran it through google translate but it didn't provide a result.  I was just wondering what it means.  I was able to get a few of the individual words through but not the full quote.
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aristotle, [Nic.Eth. 1100b.30](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0053%3Abekker%20page%3D1100b%3Abekker%20line%3D30):

> ὄμως δὲ και ἐν τούτοις διαλάμπει τὸ καλὸν, ἐπειδὰν φέρῃ τις εὐκόλως πολλὰς καὶ μεγάλας
> ἀτυχίας, μη δι᾿ ἀναλγησίαν, ἀλλὰ γεννάδας ὤν καὶ μεγαλόψυχος.

> > Yet even in these nobility shines through, when a man bears with resignation many great misfortunes, not through insensibility to pain but through nobility and greatness of soul.

---

*Note*: the quote is not part of the text of Boethius' [*De philosophiae consolatione*](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/De_philosophiae_consolatione). It is due to the editor of the [English translation](http://catalog.lambertvillelibrary.org/texts/Medieval/boethius/consolation.htm).

Comment: thank you.  nice quote. I'll take your word for it.